# I seem to be dying for some reason on inhospitable planets

Tags: spore

Every now and then when hanging around a T0 planet my ship suddenly starts taking a lot of damage for no clear reason. I know it's not from destructive geysers because they provide obvious knockback. It also seems to occur only on planets with a reasonable amount of atmosphere. What's up here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T0 planets have various hazards depending on their climate - rock/fire/ice/water geysers, storms and meteor showers make an appearance. In your particular circumstance, I think the storms are to blame, since they only manifest on high atmosphere planets.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you are near the surface of a T0 planet, you will take damage, you dont need to be near a geyser.

Answer (score 2):

Planets with a lot of atmosphere have lightning storms. The damage you get is probably from these.